# selecting rows with min and max values of a defined column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, max, min

I have the following dataframe:

```
A,B,C,D   
10,1,2,3
 1,4,7,3
10,5,2,3
40,7,9,3
9,9,9,9
```

I would like to create another dataframe starting from the previous one which have only two row.  The selection of these two rows is based on the minimum and maximum value in the column "A". I would like to get:

```
A,B,C,D   
 1,4,7,3
40,7,9,3
```

Do you think I should work with a sort of index.min e index.max and then select only the two rows and append then in a new dataframe? Do you have same other suggestions?

Thanks for any kind of help,
Best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC you can simply subset the dataframe with an `OR` condition on `df.A.min()` and `df.A.max()`:

```
df = df[(df.A==df.A.min())|(df.A==df.A.max())]
```

---

```
df
    A   B   C   D
1   1   4   7   3
3   40  7   9   3
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `idxmin/idxmax` and then use `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['A'].agg(['idxmin','idxmax']) ]
```

Output:

```
    A  B  C  D   
1   1  4  7  3
3  40  7  9  3
```

Note that this only gives one row for min and one for max. If you want all values, you should use @CHRD's solution.